# SQL query extracting a collection with join

Tags: sql, collections

I have two DB tables:

> TABLE_1(ID, ThatID, OtherField)
>
> TABLE_2(ThatID, Field2, ThoseOthers)

`ID` & `ThatID` are the keys of `TABLE_1` & `TABLE_2` resply. 
`ThatID` repeats in `TABLE_1`. `Field2` depends on `ThatID` on `TABLE_2`.

In the outcome, I need to extract the following objects for each `ThatID`:

> ThatID, Field2, Collection< OtherField>

What's the SQL query to do this?

I can't change the table structures-- these 2 are the ones i should work on.

I can't use Hibernate-- I only have JDBC in this system.

I'm looking to do an SQL-based solution-- not a Java one. So, querying 
`TABLE_1`, putting the `OtherField` values for each `ThatID` to a collection, and getting 
the matching `Field2` from the other table is not the solution.

I'm rusty on SQL, and looking for the efficient solution.

TIA.

//=================================

**EDIT:**

> **TABLE_1:**
>
> ID:   ThatID  OtherField
>
> 1     z4  other87
>
> 2 z4  other39
>
> 3     z4  this1
>
> 4     x2  axy66
>
> 5 x2  tyz44
>
> **TABLE_2:**
>
> ThatID Field2  ThoseOthers
>
> x2     Apples  somethingElse
>
> z4     Oranges someother
>
> y4     Pears   yetAnother

should produce 2 objects:

> z4, Apples, < Other87, Other39, this1>
>
> x2, Oranges, < axy66, tyz44>

//=============================================

**EDIT2:**

In this example, can i place multiple `OtherField` entries for each specific `ThatID` row of `TABLE_1` into a collection directly out of a query? I'm using SQL server.

Comment: IN which table the Fields and  Collection column are?

Comment: Can you please supply sample data and desired results?  Also, which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: @Piyush - pls see edits and corrections.

Comment: Which DBMS, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @sgeddes - pls see edits and corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `group_concat` (this assumes `mysql` based on your history of questions -- other databases have similar approaches)?

```
select that.id, that.field2, group_concat(this.otherfield)
from that 
  inner join this on that.id = this.thatid
group by that.id, that.field2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7171/1)

---

Edit, given your edits about `sql server`, you're looking for `stuff` with `for xml`:

```
select that.id, that.field2, 
    stuff((
          select ',' + this.otherfield
          from this
          where that.id = this.thatid
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from that
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7171/5)

Comment: i think this is it. wont be able to check till tomorrow but will accept ur answer.

Comment: group_concat is not the SQL Server function? is it

Comment: @Roam -- since you're using `sql server`, see edits.

Comment: @Piyush -- Just saw OP edits -- I can't type that fast :)  Need to use `stuff` for this one...

Comment: does this `for xml` have anything to do with xml-- an xml file? is stuff a keyword on sql server?

Comment: @Roam -- no, it's just a way to perform the group concat in sql server.  Other RDBMS systems make it easier than `sql server`.  And yes, `stuff` is something specific to sql server.  When used with `for xml`, you can mimic the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand your question, you need join to match your tables based on common column called `ThatID`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_1.ThatID, Field2,
stuff((
        select ',' + TABLE_1.otherfield
        from TABLE_1
        where TABLE_2.thatid = TABLE_1.thatid
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')    
FROM TABLE_2 INNER JOIN TABLE_1 ON TABLE_2.ThatID = TABLE_1.ThatID
GROUP BY TABLE_1.ThatID,TABLE_2.ThatID, Field2, OtherField
```